# Удаление файлов из БД mysql

Tags: php

Я начинающий, и постараюсь более корректней описать свой вопрос) Допустим есть чат, на одну страницу выводиться по 20 сообщений, навигация состоит из 10-ти страниц, то есть на каждой из этих страниц по 20 сообщений от пользователей) вопрос, как можно сделать так чтобы все сообщения не входящие в эти страницы удалялись автоматически? я пока только обдумываю, еще не начинал реализацию этого )

Comment: @NoProblems, Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, при добавлении 201 сообщения удалять запись с минимальным индексом в таблице.

1) получаем количество сообщений

```
SELECT COUNT(id_messages) FROM `messages`
```

2) 10 страниц по 20 сообщений = 200. Если кол-во сообщений из п.1 >= 200, то удаляем первую запись в таблице

```
DELETE FROM `messages` ORDER BY `id_messages` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Если у сообщения есть время, то лучше вместо `id_messages` подставить колонку времени.

3) Добавляем сообщение

Comment: А можно по подробней?

Comment: Немного расписал в сообщении, или нужно совсем подробно?

Comment: Спасибо, тут я думаю разберусь. спасибо :)

Comment: @Cообщество ХэшКод  а это кто???

Comment: @Cообщество ХэшКод а это кто???
Это я случайно галочку поставил, когда правил ответ))

Comment: А это типа общий ОТВЕТ! :)